# Incomplete sentences

Tags: english, reference-request, sentences, spoken-language

I am looking for studies which looks at understanding and preference of incomplete sentences.

For example, is there a higher workload for (in)complete sentences or even though the sentence might be fully understandable with the key information people might still prefer the complete sentence.

I am interested in this question for an verbal context but a written context would be great as well.

Comment: I didn't understand what your question, based on your tags your talking about comprehension of incomplete sentences in speech right?

Comment: I am looking if there is any research of complete vs incomplete sentences in speech.